# ReactJS making a decorator with React.cloneElement: can't set new child's class (className)

Tags: reactjs

I have an app like this, which uses various "thingies" of different kinds.   It knows what `stuff` should be in the thingies:

```
function Thingy(props) {
  const {top_stuff, bottom_stuff} = props;

  return (
    <div className="a-thingy">
      <div>Today's thingy...</div>
      <div className="top">
        {top_stuff}
      </div>
      <div className="bottom">
          {bottom_stuff}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

It also needs to do some more sophisticated things with the Thingies, like putting a button along side them, or changing the way they layout.

So I want to provide these extras with a Decorator.  The Decorator doesn't need to know anything about any sort of `stuff`

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
        <div className="title">
            Decorator issue 
        </div>
        <Decorator>
          <Thingy top_stuff='top' bottom_stuff='bottom'/>
        </Decorator>
     </div>
  );
}
```

This looks nice and clean: the App tells the Thingy what is in it, and it Decorates the Thingy the way it wants.

Anything that the Decorator does with css should clearly be in the Decorator css definition.   This means that the Decorator needs a way of pointing at the Thingy in css.

I tried to annotate the Thingy's class name:

```
function Decorator({children}) {
  return (
    <div className="decorator">
        <div className="decorator-heading">decorator</div>
        {React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(children), 
          {className: "decorated"})}
        <button>Do Stuff With Content</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

... but that doesn't work.

Why is this?    ( [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7b3my?file=/src/App.js:614-903) )

For clarification: I want the parent (Decorator) to be able to modify the `className` that the child has, so that the Decorator css can target that child by class name.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, the reason it didn't work is because you're passing `className` from `<Decorator />` but NOT using it inside `<Thingy />`.

So to make that work

```
function Thingy(props) {
  const { top_stuff, bottom_stuff } = props;

  return (
    // here, concat props.className (passed from <Decorator />)
    // make sure you have a space between classes
    <div className={`a-thingy ${props.className}`}>
      <div>The thingy...</div>
      <div className="top">{top_stuff}</div>
      <div className="bottom">{bottom_stuff}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now, you can control `Thingy` styles from `Decorator` like this

```
/* Thingy styles */
.decorated {
  color: red;
}
/* top style */
.decorated .top {
  color: blue;
}
```

[CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-https-9s2mv?file=/src/App.js:584-927)

Comment: I see what you mean.  I was trying to say "put this string on the class of thingy" but all I achieved was putting it on `thingy.props.className`.   :cry:    The thing is, the `thingies` should not have to need to know that they will be decorated.     The solution you offer works, but it requires cooperation from the coder of the `thingy`.

Comment: If that's the case, I think you just need to refer to the correct `className` of `Thingy` inside your `Decorator` CSS, and remove the `React.cloneElement` part since you don't need it. Like this `.decorator .a-thingy {...your CSS here}`. 

The parent and child component need to know about each other in some ways. In this case, the child `className` must always be `.a-thingy` for it to work.

Other than that, I don't think we have other ways to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: But that is assuming the decorator will be decorating `a-thingy`.  It needs to be able to decorate `any-thing`.   Note that it is the parent of Decorator that is deciding what's inside Decorator.   That's why Decorator wants to put a className on it, to talk about it in css.